# Twilio & Flask SMS response never being triggered

Tags: python, flask, twilio, twilio-api

We are working on a bot that sends and receives SMS with a conditional response system. Using Twilio, we've followed the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-python) to give us the below code. Our group has limited experience with both Flask and Twilio and we're not sure which this is a question of, but our `incoming_sms()` method is never called. The documentation seems to lack a direct calling of this so we assume it's an event triggered on a text coming into our Twilio number, but when we test this nothing is done. Our web hook shows that the message is being picked up (shown below).

Are we missing a step to trigger the `incoming_sms()` function?

```
from twilio.rest import Client
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
from twilio import twiml

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/sms", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def incoming_sms():
    body = request.values.get('Body', None)
    resp = twiml.Response()
    if body == 'Hello':
        resp.message("Answer 1")
    else:
        resp.message("Answer 2")
    
    return str(resp)

app.run(debug=True)
```

`POST` method picked up by Webhook:

```
ToCountry=US
ToState=FL
SmsMessageSid=SM8990a3baba3e88f412c9eed1b1f4ae14
NumMedia=0
ToCity=
FromZip=07960
SmsSid=SM8990a3baba3e88f412c9eed1b1f4ae14
FromState=XX
SmsStatus=received
FromCity=XXXXX
Body=Oh+Jac&FromCountry=US
To=%2B12393091468
ToZip=
NumSegments=1
ReferralNumMedia=0
MessageSid=SM8990a3baba3e88f412c9eed1b1f4ae14
AccountSid=AC87f189511d21d6480cdc84350cbbbb84
From=+1XXXXXXXXX
ApiVersion=2010-04-01
```

Comment: is this all the code in your python file?

Comment: yes, as well as it is all the code in the tutorial linked in the question

Comment: you added app.run()! That wasn't there before. What is the HTTP status code in your ngrok terminal tab when you run the app?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just downloaded ngrok. Before I was just running the python script from the terminal. How can I use this new tool?

Comment: By adding the `flask-ngrok` package and running with ngrok, I got some permission errors as well as this: `127.0.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2022 12:06:28] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 ` `127.0.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2022 12:06:28] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

Comment: This is an old blog post https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/10/test-your-webhooks-locally-with-ngrok.html, but you must configure your Twilio phone # with your Ngrok URL. What port is your app running on? Then you run `ngrok http {insert-port}` and append "/sms" to your URL when you configure your Twilio #

Comment: I'm guessing your ngrok is running on a different port as your Python app